# Visibility of multiple tenants in Azure

Tags: azure

Scenario:
A user who has been assigned CO-Owner status of a billing account in Azure wants to create a second tenant.  When this tenant is created, a new directory is created.  Once changed over to that directory, the CO-owner creates a subscription, along with resources.

Here is the question:  Should the billing OWNER also be able to see the new tenant, subscriptions, etc, or just the CO-owner who created the 2nd tenant?

The first time I did this, the OWNER of the account could not "see" the second tenant in any way.

Answer (score 0):

No, the new tenant has all new user configuration, so initially only the person who created it will have access. You will need to assign additional users as required.

Comment: Sam, thank you for bringing clarity to this.  The account owner made me co-owner and said I should be able to do whatever he can do.  But it appears that the only way he can see billing for any new tenants is for him to create the tenant himself.  Is that correct?

Comment: Co-owner is a subscription setting and doesn't really help you here. He doesn't need to be the one to create the tenant, but you will need to add him as a user in that tenant. You can either create a new user account for him, or you can invite his user from the original tenant as a guest user.

Comment: I am working with the account owner who would be according to what I'm reading the "Account Administrator".  It is tied to his email address.  Should he change his email address to a generic email address like azureadmin@someorg.net?  This part is a little tricky.  We need to be able to create new tenants which represent other companies but the subscriptions flow through to the account administrator.  I tried adding him as a guest to the tenant I created but he could not see the subscription or billing.  Not sure how to approach this.